# Style tag dynamically added to body, then removed

Tags: jquery, css

I need to achieve disabling a button, and the only way to do it, is by attaching a stylesheet to the DOM defining some classes that will imitate a disabled button. It's ungly, but it's the only solution that works for this...

So on some specific event I'll be running this JS: `$('<style>.gpay-card-info-container { pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.7; }</style>').appendTo('body');`

What I want is a way to later (on another event) delete that... Can I add an id to the style element, so later I can do something like `$(style#some-id).remove();` ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There are far better ways to accomplish your objective by targeting specific ancestor elements and let CSS inheritance do the rest.